# Find phone number in a string and format

Tags: c#, sql-server, regex, formatting

I have strings with un-formatted phone numbers, is there any way to find them and format the number and save?

Sample strings I have are

```
Name: Tippu     
Phone: 408.273.3939
Email: tippu@tippu.com
```

another sample

```
Contact Tippu at (408) 363 2323
```

In these examples I need to find the phone number and change it to NNN-NNN-NNNN format.
Data is in SQL Server and I am using c#.

Thanks

Comment: If they are stored in database why don't you use the column to get them?

Comment: Entire string is stored in a single column

Comment: Any phone number, or are you assuming North America only?

Comment: Yes all the phone numbers will be USA numbers only

Comment: Hi, did any of the answers given solve your issue? If so, it is good practice to tick one as the answer. This serves future visitors and is good for the answerer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following pseudocode.

```
string.Replace(/\(?(\d{3})[)(-.\s]*(\d{3})[)-.\s]*(\d{4})/, "$1-$2-$3")
```

It will replace both the provided examples in `NNN-NNN-NNNN` format.
Let me explain you the regex a bit.
`\(?` in the beginning looks if the string is starting with a bracket
`(\d{3})` looks for three numeric digits, and make a capturing group.
`[)(-.\s]*` looks for `)` `(` `-` `.` and a `space`. `*` makes sure to take care of the case where bracket is followed by a space.
`\d{4}` looks for 4 digits.
Here `$1` `$2` and `$3` are the capture groups. You can use them according to your language.
I believe, you can probably use `Regex.Replace()` function in C#

Comment: I agree, it was just to help him get some hint on how to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Probably not the best... 
But this is something like what I would do if it were me. It might at least help. Firstly, I assume that the last numbers in your strings represent the phone number:

```
x = <your string>.replace(/[^0-9]/g,'');
x = x.substring(x.length-10);
x = x.substring(0,3) +'-'+ x.substring(3,6) + '-' + x.substring(6);
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming Your Phone number is in this format - "408.273.3939"
then this would be helpful to you

```
 var stringText = "408.273.3939";
            var phoneArr = stringText.Split('.');
            String.Format("%s-%s-%s", phoneArr[0], phoneArr[1], phoneArr[2]);
```

Moreover your question is also not clear to me.